# jquery ui dynamic icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, button

I have a set of buttons and Im trying to instead of setting individual icons for them, use an attribute and one-for-all function to set their icon. Here is an example of my button :

```
<button title="New Project" id="New" class="Nx button" type="document"></button>
```

and here is sort of what I want to achieve :

```
$('.button').button({
   icons: { primary:'ui-icon-'+$(this).attr("type") },
   text:false
});
```

but it doesnt work. so pretty much I want to have an internal reference to the element's "type" attribute to be able to set the icon

Comment: You could use CSS styles assigning icons to them using `url`s to point to the icons. Even if you programmatically switch them then you simply switch classes and CSS take care of it.

Comment: I think `this` references window because your are passing it from the outer scope, so you are actually passing the type attribute of the window object. try something like `$('.button').each(function(i,btn) {var type = $(btn).attr('type'); $(btn).button(...);} )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of how I would go about it. I have also provided the code below. Let me know if you need anything else.

CODE:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").each(function(index,element){
       $(element).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-" + $(this).attr('type')
            },
                text:false
            })
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/sZdd8/11/